How to create Ubuntu machine on ESXi 6.5 which is installed on VirtualBox?
failed to connect screenshot
 --vm_screenshot
Been trying to create a machine on ESXi 6.5 which is installed as a virtual machine on VirtualBox.
The install of ESXi as virtual machine was succesful.
The problem is that I need to install Ubuntu as VM on this ESXi which is also a VM
I upload the ISO image file of Ubuntu into the ESXi virtual HDD and when I start the machine it fails.
ESXi and host operating system are working with host only adapter and successfully ping each other.
something else i did was adding the ubuntu ISO file as CD inside virtualbox vm's controllers

You have enabled nested virtualization within VirtualBox?

You’re going to need to provide a log or error or something. Just saying it’s failing to boot definitely isn’t enough information to diagnose the problem. You’ll need to [edit] your question to include those additional details

Yes nested virtualization enabled

The solution is update your ESXi install.. However, without specifics, I cannot submit an answer

Tried it with VMware Workstation Player 17 and worked fine, thanks!
Nothing special, just continued with installation on everything and booted ubuntu inside esxi inside vmware player

I mean, you could switch one desktop virtual machine engine for another, but that's not really an answer to your original question IMO

Yes but I couldnt seem to find any solutions

Also, there is no point I guess running ESXi as a VM except for educational or academic purposes. I mean that this thing is meant to run on bare metal.
